# State Monad with multiple state values

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

Consider the following:

```
do
  x1 <- new 2
  set x1 3
  x2 <- get x1
  y1 <- new 10
  set y1 20
  y2 <- get y1
  return (x2 + y2)
```

I want this to result in `23`. Is there a way to implement something like this in pure Haskell, and if so how? I understand `STRef` does something like this, but I just want to do it in ordinary Haskell (not worried about efficiency at the moment). I presume I'll have to make a data type and make it an instance of `Monad`, but I'm not sure of the details, so a working example would be helpful.

Comment: Is your question just about implementing mutable references or do you also need to learn how to implement a pure state monad?

Comment: Pure state. No need for an actual mutable implementation. If this already exists a link to the hackage page will be fine. The issue with this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html is that one seems to be able to `put` the entire state, not a particular "variable"

Comment: In your code, `x1` and `y1` seem to be variables, while `x2` and `y2` seem to be values; these will have to have different types, so I find the naming surprising. Are you aware of that?

Comment: I wasn't aware, but yes, I see your point. The naming is ordinary, but I won't change that now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ordinary. In Haskell, a variable of type `Integer` is something completely different than a named reference in some state; I really suggest to not give confusing names there.

Comment: Sorry, by "ordinary" I mean "bad". I was being loose with my English.

Comment: Ah, I see. In fact, “ordinary” means “normal”, „regular”, so quite the opposite :-)

Comment: I was using it in the "of inferior quality; second-rate" sense, but I see the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

This allows more than one value, but it's hairier :) This is nicely simplified with Daniel's suggestion of `Dynamic`.

```
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Map as M

newtype Ref a = Ref {ref :: Int}

type MutState = State (Int, Map Int Dynamic)

val :: Typeable a => Ref a -> MutState a
val r = snd `fmap` get >>= 
        return . fromJust . (>>= fromDynamic) .  M.lookup (ref r)

new :: Typeable a => a -> MutState (Ref a)
new a = do
  (curr, binds) <- get
  put (curr + 1, M.insert (curr + 1) (toDyn a) binds)
  return . Ref $ curr + 1

set :: Typeable a => Ref a -> a -> MutState ()
set (Ref i) a = do
  (c, m) <- get
  put (c, M.insert i (toDyn a) m)

runMut :: MutState a -> a
runMut = flip evalState (0, M.fromList [])
```

Then to use it

```
default (Int) -- too lazy for signatures :)
test :: Int
test = runMut $ do
  x1 <- new 2
  set x1 3
  x2 <- val x1
  y1 <- new 10
  set y1 20
  y2 <- val y1
  return (x2 + y2)
```

`Ref`s are basically `Int`s with some type information attached and `val` will look up the appropriate `Dynamic` and attempt to force it into the correct type.

If this was real code, you should hide the implementations of `Ref` and `MutState`. For convenience, I've `fromJust`ed the return of `val` bur if you want a safe implementation I suppose you could layer `State` and `Maybe` monads to deal with unbound variables.

And in case you are worried about the typeable constraints, as shown above they are trivially derived.

Comment: Why reimplement [`Dynamic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Dynamic.html)?

Comment: @DanielWagner Simplified thank you! you know one day I'm going to post an answer without you posting a comment showing how needlessly overcomplicated it is ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is an implementation already in `Control.Monad.State`, but it is cumbersome for generality sake: one complication comes from MonadState class, and another from the fact that plain `State` is implemented in terms of more general `StateT`.

Here is an example of your task using that implementation. No mutability was used. Note that your example was pasted as is, just adding `x` prefix:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map as M

type MyMap a = M.Map Int a
type MyState a b = State (MyMap a) b
type MyRef = Int

xrun :: MyState a b -> b
xrun x = evalState x (M.empty)

mget :: MyState a (MyMap a)
mget = get

mput :: MyMap a -> MyState a ()
mput = put

mmodify :: (MyMap a -> MyMap a) -> MyState a ()
mmodify x = modify x

xnew :: s -> MyState s MyRef
xnew val = do
    s <- mget
    let newRef = if M.null s then 0 else fst (M.findMax s) + 1
    mput $ M.insert newRef val s
    return newRef

xset :: MyRef -> a -> MyState a () 
xset ref val = modify $ M.insert ref val

xget :: MyRef -> MyState a a
xget ref = fmap (\s -> case M.lookup ref s of Just v -> v) get

test :: MyState Int Int
test = do
  x1 <- xnew 2
  xset x1 3
  x2 <- xget x1
  y1 <- xnew 10
  xset y1 20
  y2 <- xget y1
  return (x2 + y2)

main = print $ xrun test
```

It is possible to implement all the functions in the module and `>>=`/`return` without using stock implementations from `Control.Monad` preserving the signatures.

Here it is:

```
module MyState (State, get, put, modify, evalState) where

newtype State s a = State (s -> (a, s))

evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
evalState (State f) = fst . f

instance Monad (State s) where
    return a = State $ \s -> (a, s)
    State f >>= g = State $ \s -> 
        case f s of 
            (a', s') -> case g a' of 
                State h -> h s'

instance Functor (State s) where
    fmap f (State g) = State $ 
        \s -> case g s of (a, s) -> (f a, s) 

get :: State s s
get = State (\s -> (s, s))

put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)

modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
modify f = get >>= put . f
```

Save it to `MyState.hs` and replace `import Control.Monad.State` with `import MyState`.

Comment: I had that answer first as well (got downvoted and then deleted by me), but if you look closely you’ll see that Clinton wants to track variables in the state, not just one state, so something like the `ST` monad.

Comment: I think something like `type MyState a b = State (M.Map Int a, Int) b` will do the job for him. I'm elaborating the answer now

Comment: that’s what I wrote below. Note that you don’t need the second Int, you can easily (and efficiently) get the largest index in a Map.

Answer (score 2):

With `State` or `StateT` you could emulate it (`State` allow only 1 value). The easiest way is use `Map`:

```
 do
  put empty
  set "x1" 3  
  x2 <-  getKey "x1"
  set "y1" 20
  y2 <-  getKey "y1"
  return (x2 + y2)
    where
      getKey k = fromJust . (lookup k) `fmap` get
      set = modify replace
      replace d k m = if k `member` m then update (\_ -> Just d) k m
                      else insert k d m
```

Comment: I'd rather not to string lookups in a map. I know I said I wasn't worried about efficiency, but that seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: @Clinton if you have 200 .. values, it isn't efficient. It's only `O(log n)`

Answer (score 2):

How about StateT for a tuple?

```
flip evalState (2, 10) $ do
  modify $ \(_, y) -> (3, y)
  x2 <- fst <$> get
  modify $ \(x, _) -> (x, 20)
  y2 <- snd <$> get
  return (x2 + y2)
```

If you actually want mutable cells, I'd recommend using ST, STM, or IO instead of StateT.  The implementation using StateT over a heterogeneous map from increasing naturals to objects seems possible but probably a bit awkward.

Comment: Interestingly `\(_, y) -> (3, y)` is the same as `(first . const) 3`.